# Xcode 8 don't have iOS10 simulators

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I updated Xcode to verison 8.0 (8A218a) and i don't have iOS10 simulators.
[image: No simulators]

Latest simulator i can download from Preferences -> Components is 9.3.

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution

Go on "Add Additional Simulators..." from picture in answer, then add them manually.

[image: Manually adding simulators]

Comment: can't add additional simulator, after click on create button

Comment: You probably trying to add iPhone 4s witch not supporting iOS10. Just choose another Device Type

Comment: Works for me. Meanwhile Xcode 8 is for iOS8, this happens. Hunting iOS10 device simulators.